# How does 0..* and End(s) work on this UML?

Tags: java, interface, uml, diagram

As the title says,can you help me understand how does the 0..* affects the last class in this UML? I will also post the code i wrote for it,i don't have any errors but i don't understand how to implement the Ends and the 0..*/0..1

[image]

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public  class MyHomeSecurity  {
    private ArrayList<Security> allSecurity= new ArrayList<Security>();

    public void addSecurity(Security mySecure){
       allSecurity.add(mySecure);
    }

    public void removeSecurity(Security mySecure){
        allSecurity.remove(mySecure);
    }

    public void information(){
        System.out.println("Information");
    }

    public ArrayList<Security> getAllSecurity() {
        return allSecurity;
    }

    public void setAllSecurity(ArrayList<Security> allSecurity) {
        this.allSecurity = allSecurity;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. By calling `addSecurity` you are referencing 0..* `Securities`. So what is your point

Comment: I'm sorry,english is not my first language and i might have trouble explaining myself. I also posted a picture in the link if you looked at it. And the description for this code that i posted is : "MyHomeSecurity is a concerete class. allSecurity is a property saves the all security objects related to one MyHomeSecurity object(ArrayList usage is suggested). addSecurity() method adds a new security object in the list. removeSecurity() method removes a security object from the list. information() method lists all the information related to security objects."

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `0..1` and `0..*` is a constraint which will be implemented differently depending on the language you use. Mostly you need to implement that constraint on a collection by checking that the number of elements is zero or one (in the `0..1` case). If you are using Swift you can use `Optional` which has either a value or is `nil`. I guess for Java you can also use `nil` to detect if something is assigned or not (so your `Cypher` is either `nil` or points to some object).

The `0..*` case is simply a collection which is handled similar in most OO languages (sometimes as array of varying size).